# How to make sure my git pre-commit script won't get fooled?

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit-hook

I'm writing a git pre-commit script and encountered a few difficulties along the way. The first one I came across is the changes that were made after the files were added to the index. For example :

- I write a small `test.py` script
- I add it to the index using `git add test.py`
- I change something in `test.py` (but don't `git add` those changes)
- I commit the previously added file

Then it triggers my pre-commit script which happens to read `test.py` to make sure nothing's wrong with it. The thing is, the on-its-way-to-be-committed `test.py` and the one in my working tree are different !! So my script is basically checking the wrong file and may miss some very important issues with the code. After a bit of research I found out that some people do a `git stash push` at the beginning of the hook and a `git stash pop` at the end, to "make sure" the pre-commit script is analyzing the committed version of the file but I find it to be a bit risky (see below why I think that) and I really don't like the idea of performing git commands while running a script triggered by a git command. So **my first question is : what's the best way to make sure I'm analyzing the on-its-way-to-be-committed file and not the one in my working tree ?** Maybe I could try to read `.git/objects/*` files directly ?

That git stash stuff made me wonder... What if a dev at my company who's using my pre-commit script decides to switch branch in another terminal while the pre-commit script is running ? Well, I already know the answer as I did some testing : the commit will fail with `fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD'` and the `git stash pop` will occur in this other branch and probably cause conflicts. Another scenario could be that the dev modifies the file after the stash push and before it has been loaded by my pre-commit script, causing my script to analyze the wrong file content once again, this is basically a race condition in which a human is involved. I do realize those scenarios are kinda twisted but devs at my company are not all familiar with git and I definitely feel like this is something that could happen... So **my second question is : how can I make sure the working tree will stay intact after my pre-commit has done its job, even if the dev does some crazy stuff in the meantime ?** I was hoping git would create some sort of lock file during the hook which would prevent devs from doing weird things, but it appears it doesn't.

I guess if there's a good way to answer my first question, the second one is irrelevant, but I asked it anyway just in case. Can't wait to read what y'all have to say !

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You cannot force devs to use the pre-commit hooks. They can simply disable them, overwrite them with something else or run `git commit --no-verify`. Isn't that something you want to do in your CI pipeline on the server? Running linters, checking the code for compile errors, running tests. Personally, I get really (_really_) annoyed when a commit takes longer than a second. Sometimes I simply want to quickly save progress and later clean up; if the pre-commit hook rejected my commit, I would be very angry at whoever installed the hook.

Comment: I would say these "kinda twisted" scenarios you are considering will never happen unless your hook takes ages to run (which is a problem in itself), and devs can just skip the hook entirely with `--no-verify`. If you don't want to do the stash stuff, you could just abort the commit if there are unstaged changes, then let the dev make sure to properly stage everything before committing. Though, that can be annoying to others (see above comment). If there's some check that *really* must run, it has to be a remote-side op.

Comment: I do realize client-side hooks can easily be bypassed and we already have many checks performed in our CI pipeline. But our CI is very very very slow (for various legitimate reasons) so I was willing to share this pre-commit script with my colleagues so that basic mistakes can be identified before reaching the server (which is overloaded pretty much all the time).

Comment: My pre-commit script is pretty fast I would say, but I'd like to handle edge cases where a dev commits many changes in many files, I guess it could potentially take a long time to run static analysis on each file and I don't want them to struggle with git because they decided to switch branch while the pre-commit script was doing its work.

Comment: @GinoMempin "let the dev make sure to properly stage everything before committing" that sounds annoying tbh.... It's probably the best way to make sure they will disable the hook forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then it triggers my pre-commit script which happens to read test.py to make sure nothing's wrong with it. The thing is, the on-its-way-to-be-committed test.py and the one in my working tree are different !!

That's why you need to make sure your `pre-commit` script runs on files in the index, *not* on your work tree. It's actually very common for staged commits to be different from what's actually in the work tree (consider, for example, `git add -p`, which lets you stage portions of files).

One way of handling this is to check out the index into a temporary directory and run your tests there. You can use the [`git checkout-index`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git-checkout-index.1.html) command to check out a copy of the index into a temporary directory.

Here's an example `pre-commit` hook that will reject a commit if any files contain the word `BAD`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "running checks"

# create a temporary directory
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d precommitXXXXXX)

# make sure we clean it up when we're done
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" EXIT

# check out the index
git checkout-index --prefix=$tmpdir/ -af

# run tests in a subshell so that we end up back in the current
# directory when everything finishes.
(
  cd $tmpdir
  
  if grep -q BAD *; then
    echo "ERROR: found bad files"
    exit 1
  fi
)
```

I believe this also addresses your second question about ensuring that the tree you're testing stays consistent during the tests. Because here you're working in a temporary directory with a copy of the repository, you don't need to worry about anything changing.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I believe I've seen this somewhere but wasn't able to reproduce so I gave up on it. I was missing the trailing `/`, now it works perfectly ! However I'm working on a big project and the checkout takes quite a long time (between 0.6 and 0.7 s). Add to that the processing of my pre-commit script and I'm afraid devs will be totally annoyed... I think I will rather chose to read `.git/objects/` as it seems to be way faster (and hopefully as safe). Yet, your answer remains correct so I marked it so for future Googlers :)

Comment: Little update for future Googlers : don't read `.git/objects` directly as I said. If you don't want to copy the whole index you can simply pass files to checkout in the command line like so : `git checkout-index --prefix=$(mktemp -d precommitXXXXXX) -f -- file1 file2 file3`

Comment: Those files in the index can be obtained by using `git diff-index --cached HEAD`

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hard problem, if you want to tackle it in its full generality (`git commit`, `git commit -a`, `git commit --only foo`, `git commit --include bar`, plus the other items you have mentioned).

Someone has made a pretty darn good solution that you can just use.  I have never used it myself, so I'm not specifically *recommending* it here, but take a look at https://pre-commit.com/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already heard of the pre-commit framework, it looks great but I don't want to bother with an external dependency for now. I'm not sure what you meant though by `if you want to tackle it in its full generality (git commit, git commit -a, git commit --only foo, git commit --include bar`. Isn't git pre-commit hook triggered in any of these cases ?

Comment: While the pre-commit hook is indeed run in each of those cases, they all result in a different *way* the pre-commit hook must operate, depending on what you intend to do *in* that pre-commit hook. In particular `git commit --only` results in *three* index files being active during the commit. You have to be very careful about which one you use for what purpose.